# Why does a for loop that start int i = 6 takes longer than int i = 0?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have programmed the Sieve of Eratosthenes in C but my for loop takes longer when I start with int i = 6.

```
int *tmp = NULL;

tmp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000000);

tmp[0] = 2;
tmp[1] = 3;
tmp[2] = 5;

int prim_ = 3;
bool hasdiv = false;

clock_t t;
t = clock();
for(int i = 6; i < 1000000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < prim_; j++){
        if (i % tmp[j] == 0) {
            hasdiv = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasdiv) {
        prim_++;
        tmp[prim_] = i;
    }
    hasdiv = false;
}
t = clock() - t;
double tim = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("%f",tim);
```

with

```
for(int i = 6; i < 1000000; i++) {
```

it takes 8.4 sec and with

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
```

it takes 0.009 sec. Where does the behaviour comes from?

I use VS 19 Community with MSVC 14.24.28314.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your code has a bug in that `tmp[3]` will never get initialized: you start `prim_` at `3` and increment it before assigning to `tmp[prim_]`.  So each time through the loop when `j==3`, you read uninitialized memory and your code has undefined behavior.  You may have wanted to interchange the lines `prim_++; tmp[prim_]=i;`, or simply write `tmp[prim_++]=i;`.

After fixing that, think about what happens when you go through the loop with `i==1`.  1 is not divisible by any integer greater than 1, so your code will conclude that it is prime, and will set `tmp[3]=1`.  Since every number is divisible by 1, then on every subsequent iteration of the outer loop, you will break out of the inner loop as soon as `j==3`.  That is obviously going to make it much faster than if `j` had to potentially go all the way up to `prim_`.  It is also going to make your program worthless, since it is going to decide that there are no prime numbers beyond 5.

Most logic that deals with primes needs a special case for the number 1, and this is no exception.  It really doesn't make sense at all for your program to start with a value of `i` less than 2.

Comment: I saw it yet. I have copyed the code from python forgotten that python work different.